# tinyMCE to AS3 htmlText

Tags: actionscript-3, tinymce, htmltext

I'm using tinyMCE to edit/markup text in a Zend Framework backend.
I'd like to use the generated HTML in a Flash AS3 Application.
The problem is that Flash doesn't support attributes in `<span>`'s, `<em>` tags, `<strong>` tags etc. 
I guess there are two possibilities here:

- change the tinyMCE config so it uses font-tags instead of span's, `<b>` instead of `<strong>`,...
- Replace all the HTML-tags in Flash with Regex.

Any help would be welcome.

so this is the original html generated by tinyMCE:

```
<span style="color:#FF0000; font-size:24;">text, and <strong>bold text</strong></span>
```

And this is what I need in Flash:

```
<font size='24' color='#FF0000'>text and <b>bold text</b></font>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply but I found a very simple Solution.
TinyMCE comes with a plug-in called: **legacyoutput**. This will generate old-school HTML code that's readable in Flash.

how to use this:

- add **legacyoutput** to your plugins in
  the tinyMCE init function
- add the following rule to your
  tinyMCE init function:
  **extended_valid_elements : 'b,i'**

Now your HTML will look like this:

```
<font size="12" style="color:#FF0000"><b>text in bold 14pt red</b></font>
```

The style attribute should be replaced by a color attribute to make it readable in Flash
You can fix this by editing a rule in the legacyoutput js files (tinymce/plugins/legacyoutput/editor_plugin.js and editor_plugin_src.js):

look for "forecolor" and change the code to the following:

```
forecolor : {inline : 'font', attributes : {color : '%value'}},
```

Now you can ouput this in Flash witouth using a single hack.

Answer (score 0):

First add the following to your config (this should result in using b-tags instead of strong for bold):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    formats : {
          ...
      bold : {inline : 'b'},
          ...
});
```

You should write an own plugin with the functionality to replaces your spans (using jQuery). The relevant code should look similar to this:

```
iframe_id = (ed.id == 'content_ifr') ? ed.id : ed.id+'_ifr';
spans = document.getElementById(iframe_id).document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (i=0;i<spans.length;i++){

  with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow){

    var font=document.createElement("font");
    font.innerHTML = span[i].innerHTML;
    font.size = $(span[i]).attr('font-size');
    font.color = $(span[i]).attr('color');
    span[i].parentNode.replaceChild(font, span[i]);
  }
}
```