# How to convert new font tag into old font tag with regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert this string:

```
<span style="font-family: 'book antiqua', palatino, serif; font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900;">Text Content</span>
```

into:

```
<font face='book antiqua, palatino, serif' size='14' color='#ff9900'>Text Content</font>
```

how can I do this with regular expression? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: you can use string replace function .

Comment: html `font` tag is Obsolete and no longer Supported, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font || http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: why do you want to support old tags when it is depreciated ?

Comment: I want to display html content in flash cs5 textfield which only support old html font tag

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours of googling I Finally found the solution for this problem in this forum 
[tinyMCE to AS3 htmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494555/tinymce-to-as3-htmltext)